# Encrypt logback android file

Tags: android, security, encryption, logback

I would like to know if is it possible to create CustomRollingFileAppender that use [EncryptedFile](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedFile?authuser=1) to encrypt the file. Is EncryptedFile a good solution to encrypt a file? Exist an example how to create CustomRollingFileAppender in Android Java?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is an easy way to use rotating log files with the EncryptedFile API. In general, EncryptedFile is a great solution for encrypting files ([here is an article on how to](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/data-encryption-on-android-with-jetpack-security-e4cb0b2d2a9)).

Instead of RollingFileAppender, maybe you can use Android's built in [FileHandler](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/logging/FileHandler) or [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/android/), which wraps Log4J.